# Volumetric efficiency versus pressure ratio for rotary compressor

Tags: compressors

I am trying to plot the efficiency graph of a rotary compressor.
I already calculated the volumetric & polytropic efficiencies and the graph versus evaporating temperature is as follows:

[image]

Now i would like to find the volumetric efficiency of the compressor versus pressure ratio, but what i see is not the single graph is 4 series of curves.

[image]

I have always seen in datasheet they show just one curve as the volumetric efficiency of the compressor.

Would you please tell me what is the approach to calculate the voleumetric efficiency graph of the compressor?

Comment: Why not start with the "standard" non-dimensional coefficients ie flow, load & pressure?

Answer (score 1):

your graphs indicate that the volumetric efficiency of the machine is a function of the temperature of the working fluid for high values of the pressure ratio. This is not too surprising; but it is likely that the pump manufacturer furnishes an efficiency curve for only one temperature, hence only one line on the chart.